# Best way to iterate to a part of an array based on value?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, loops, search

I have an php-array like this:

```
$students = array(
  array(1, 'James', 'Brown', 10, 50),
  array(2, 'John', 'Doe', 10, 40),
  array(3, 'Adam', 'Works', 10, 40));
```

Where the columns represent id, first name, last name, category, and level. As example I use three rows... in practice I use many more.

Now I need to group print the results based on column (category or level) and a specific value. For example, I want to print (echo) all students in category 10. I can loop through each record and check the category; if 10 then print. The same applies for level 40. Loop through the whole set again and check the level; if 40 then print.

With an eye on performance, is there a smarter way to achive this? For example, first sort or filter?

I could choose to query the database many times but I doubt if this is the best way. I guess manipulating the array is better.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: where does this array come from?

Comment: It totally depends on how many group prints you intend to do and of what type.

Comment: It *looks* like these values are from rows in a database. If they are, you're better off selecting what you want when you want it. Like `select * from students where category = 10;`, or `select * from students where level = 40;`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Ow, if that really is the case then I will use more database queries. I thought that having much database round trips will affect performance dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is with the array_filter() function. But if these values come from a database, you're probably better off writing better queries.

```
$ cat array-filter.php
<?php
$students = array(
  array(1, 'James', 'Brown', 10, 50),
  array(2, 'John', 'Doe', 10, 40),
  array(3, 'Adam', 'Works', 10, 40));

$level_40 = array_filter($students, function($a) {return $a[4]==40 ? true : false;});
print_r($level_40);
?>

$ php array-filter.php
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => John
            [2] => Doe
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Adam
            [2] => Works
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 40
        )

)
```

The callback function just compares the fifth column to the integer literal 40. The fifth column has index 4, not 5, hence the expression `$a[4]==40 ?`.

If you're getting this data from a database, you're probably better off writing better SQL. To get all the students whose level is 40, you'd write something like

```
select *
from students
where level = 40
order by student_id;
```

The result set will contain exactly the right rows, so you don't need to filter them. And they'll be in exactly the right order, so you don't need to sort them.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and useful reply. About the SQL solution... if I have 10 categories and 5 levels then I need to query the database 15 times. I doubt if that's the best way. What do you think?

Comment: If you're presenting all the categories and all the levels at once, you don't need to filter in the first place. To present all the students who fall into all 10 categories at once, select all the relevant rows sorted by category and (probably) student_id. Then walk the entire result set without filtering. Ditto for levels.

Comment: Maybe I took the most difficult solutions. Yours is much easier. Thanks!